# Что я не так делаю с selectedIndex?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

что не так?  как сделать чтобы выводилось какой выбран пункт?

```
<form name="service">
<select onchange="num()" name="select_source" id="mySelectId" class="w2">
    <option SELECTED value="justclick" >JustClick</option>
    <option SELECTED value="getresponse" >GetResponser</option>
    <option SELECTED value="mailchimp" >MailChimp</option>
    <option SELECTED value="unisender" >UniSender</option>
    <option SELECTED value="smartresponder" >SmartResponder</option>
</select>
</form> <script>
function num(){
    alert("num="+$(".select_source").options.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: @Анатолийй, вам нужно индекс выбранного элемента списка или его значение? И еще, думаю, что бессмысленно всем элементам устанавливать атрибут "selected", все сразу же не могут быть выбранны.

Comment: Селектор точка ".######" отбирает элементы с заданным классом(<tag class="######">), а не с атрибутом name. Читайте документацию и смотрите примеры в ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот.](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/qtkqrsck/) А в чем прикол всем option-ам selected поприсваивать?